# comparing two string[]

Tags: c#, asp.net

throwing me an error here:

```
string.Compare(list[], list1[],true); <<<<<<
```

is causing the error.

```
string[] list = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "v", "z" };
string[] list1 = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "v", "z" };

int result = string.Compare(list[], list1[], true);

if (result == 0)
{
    Label1.Text += "Two strings are equal";
}
else if (result == 1)
{
    Label1.Text += "Test String1 is greater than Test String2";
}
else if (result == -1)
{
    Label1.Text += "Test String1 is less than Test String2";
}
```

Comment: Please read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @Matt Ball, thecoop, Chris, Alex Aza, Oded: wow so you guys decided to close? what is ambiguous or vague about this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use SequenceEqual of Linq to check if string arrays are same

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx

Answer (score 6):

What about:

```
 bool areSame = list.SequenceEqual(list1);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will be because `string.Compare` does not have a signature for accepting arrays.

Also, when you're passing arrays around you do not need to use `[]` after the variable name as you've done.

There's a great [SO Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713341/comparing-arrays-in-c) that answers the question of how to compare two arrays.

Answer (score 1):

[`string.Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare.aspx) has no overload that takes string arrays.

You will need to write your own function to compare the arrays.

You need to decide the behavior for different length arrays, what to return for different values in the same index etc...