# Comparing two Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, compare

I am new to C# and just comparing two arrays... both arrays should be equal, as their values are same, but result is always false... not sure why.

```
char[] arOne =  { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\u0000' };
char[] arTwo = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\u0000' };
Console.WriteLine(" Two arrays are equal ? ...{0}", (arOne == arTwo) ? "true" : "false");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713341/comparing-arrays-in-c-sharp

Comment: The `==` operator on reference types is conducting a reference comparison (are those references pointing to the same object) not the content of underlying objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Two arrays are equal? ...{0}", arOne.Intersect(arTwo).Any() ? "true" : "false");
```

Comment: it will not check if tables are the same, it will return true to {0} and {0,1}

Answer (score 5):

Try and use this

[Enumerable.SequenceEqual Method (IEnumerable, IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx)

```
bool areEqual = arOne.SequenceEqual(arTwo);
```

What you are doing is comparing object references and not the actual contents of the collections.

Answer (score 3):

The `==` operator just compares the references, if they are not the same it returns `false`. You could use [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
bool bothSameChars = arOne.SequenceEqual(arTwo);
```

`SequenceEqual`takes also the order into account, if that doesn't matter you could use `HashSet<Char>` and it's [`SetEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346516%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which is very efficient:

```
HashSet<Char> charset1 = new HashSet<Char>(arOne);
HashSet<Char> charset2 = new HashSet<Char>(arTwo);
bothSameChars = charset1.SetEquals(charset2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Code...

```
Console.WriteLine(" Two arrays are equal ? ...{0}", Enumerable.SequenceEqual(arOne, arTwo) ? "true" : "false");
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are currently checking the *REFERENCE* to two objects and check if those are equal, which they obviously are not. What you want to do is check if their *CONTENT AND SEQUENCE* are equal, for which they invented the awesome function `.SequenceEqual()`. Your code will be something like

```
char[] arOne = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\u0000' };
char[] arTwo = new char[] { 'a', b', 'c', '\u0000' };
Console.WriteLine(" Two arrays are equal ? ... {0}", (arOne.SequenceEqual(arTwo)));
```

Because SequenceEqual() already returns a boolean, you don't even have to add the `? "true" : false"` anymore.