# Compare Two Arrays (One with an increment on each value in one array)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How can I compare two arrays such that:

```
array1[i+10]==array2[i]
```

Is always true?

I know the following can compare arrays, but what about this specific case?

```
bool isEqual = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(array1, array2);
```

Comment: Does this imply that `array1` has 10 more elements than `array2`?  And that the first 10 elements of `array1` don't matter?

Comment: No, just that each element in array1 is 10 more than each element in array2 so if array1[0]=10 then array2[0]=20 and so on

Comment: Oh, then your statement is wrong.  It should be `array1[i] + 10 == array2[i]`.

Comment: @DevProg That's _very_ different that what you've tried.  You want `array1[i] + 10 =array2[i]` instead.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant

Comment: @DevProg What did you try to do to accomplish this goal, and what problem(s) did you have with your attempted solutions?

Comment: I tried using for loops. However, the problem is what I want to execute a specific  statement once if ALL runs of the for loop are true. As such, I do not wish to place the statement in the body of the for loop as it will run multiple times

Comment: So put the statement _outside_ of the for loop.  When you ask incomplete questions you get incomplete answers...

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713341/comparing-arrays-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

The old-fashioned way:

```
int length = array2.Length;
bool areEqual = true;
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if(array1[i] + 10 = array2[i])
    {
        areEqual = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

The linq way:

```
var query1 = array1.Select(i => i + 10);
bool areEqual = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(query1,array2);
```

Comment: Thanks @D Stanley but I want to compare both arrays at once, i.e for all values in both arrays array1[i+10]=array2[i]

Comment: @DevProg You can't compare "all values at once" .  Even `SequenceEqual` loops behind-the-scenes.

Comment: @DevProg I've adjusted my answer based on your comment to the question.  I'd suggest editing the question appropriately.

Comment: Yes, but I do not wish to implicitly write the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The answer differs depending on what you mean by `array1[i+10]==array2[i]`.

**If the values of `array2` should be 10 more than the values of `array1`:**

Use `Select` to create a temporary array that adds 10 to each value in `array1`, then compare to `array2`:

```
bool equal2 = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(array1.Select(n => n + 10), array2);
```

---

**If the values of `array2` should be the same as `array1`, shifted over 10 places:**

Use `Skip` to jump past the first 10 elements of `array1`, then compare to `array2`:

```
bool equal = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(array1.Skip(10), array2);
```

Note that this only works if `array1` has exactly 10 more elements than `array2`.

Comment: Thanks BJ.  However, I am getting the following error: The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.SequenceEqual<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: The arrays are byte arrays

Comment: For a byte array, modify the `Select` clause to `n => (byte)(n + 10)`.